# Why am i getting the error 'Module 'curses' has no 'newwin' member'

Tags: python, curses

**i am getting the error 'Module 'curses' has no 'newwin' member' and i dont know why
i am new to curses and i am trying to make a snake game.
this is just some of the code so don't base it off that unless in good reason**

```
import random
import curses


s = curses.initscr()
#curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/4
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sh/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
```

Comment: "this is just some of the code so don't base it off that unless in good reason" - if you run just the code you've posted, what happens? Does it reproduce the same error? Show us the complete error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: that is the full error message

Comment: and yes it does happen every time

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: Are you getting the error at runtime or from Pylint?

Answer (score 0):

Your python environment didn't have curses. So just install(pip install windows-curses) it first then it will works fine. If you are using PyCharm, after installation go to the Editor Configuration and select Enumlate Terminal option.

Comment: i am using visual studio

Comment: Sorry, I am not using Visual studio. But your problem is  that you python environment does not contain curses lib. install using this command :pip install windows-curses